# How to make a connection to the postgresql database separated by schema?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

I am trying to connect to the postgresql database and everything works fine, but I do not know how to make a query to fetch data from a table that is in a schema, but it can help me.
When I consult by PgAdmin the queries I make are this:
`SELECT * FROM "public"."STORE";`

But in the C # code I can not do this query with double quotation marks and no single quotes, someone knows like the previous query by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the double quote.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM \"public\".\"STORE\";";
```

or

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM ""public"".""STORE"";";
```

You can get more info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful.